# Convert UTF-8 encoding to ISO 8859-1 encoding with NSString

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, character-encoding, nsstring

I have an application that reads the data in UTF-8 format from the server, but it has to be displayed in ISO 8859-1(Latin-1). Are there any Cocoa APIs to achieve this?

Comment: "display in ISO 8859-1" makes no sense. If you display text, characters are drawn. And characters are independent of an encoding. The encoding is used when text is stored or transmitted, but not on display.

Comment: @user543101 What part of my answer didn't sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: I agree with Codo, this makes no sense. Taking ISO-8859-1 encoded characters and just serializing them as UTF-8 is only ok because ISO-8895-1 was incorporated as the first 256 codepoints, but this would fail with any other encoding and could fail if you're not actually using ISO-8859-1 (e.g., using 8859-15 or Windows-1252). The server should be sending proper UTF-8 encoded Unicode codepoints and you should simply be displaying the associated glyphs.

Comment: @Jason While the question's motive may not make sense, there is still an answer.

Comment: @Jacob The question is systemic of another problem, and it needs to be pointed out that this solution will only reliably work with 8859-1. Any other encoding serialized this way, or even a variant of 8859-1 can fail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s [`getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJGIEIE) method, like this:

```
char converted[([string length] + 1)];
[string getCString:converted maxLength:([string length] + 1) encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%s", converted);
```

Once you have this, you can then re-initialize an `NSString` instance from that same encoding using the `stringWithCString:encoding:` class method:

```
NSString *converted_str = [NSString stringWithCString:converted encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` because it doesn't require you to guess how much storage to allocate, and the returned NSData tells you how many bytes were required.

Answer (score 0):

Jacobs answer didn't really work for my. What did eventually work for me was to only use

```
[username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
+ (id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

Example:

```
latinStringForDisplay = [NSString stringWithCString:yourCstringHere encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

That should do it.

Comment: This function make NSString from latin1 buffer :) Author asks about reverse operation.

Comment: @Evgen: That function ask for a C string `yourCstringHere`, and outputs an NSSring with Latin encoding, not from a latin buffer as what you've quoted in: "...make NSString from latin1 buffer :)" Thanks:-)

Comment: It doesn't. Your code is saying that the C string is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and you want an NSString. So if he had the string "åhus" encoded as UTF-8 but from latin-1 he'd have a byte stream like: C3 A5 68 75 73 and your method would generate the NSString: "Ã¥hus" which is clearly wrong.