# MD5 hashes from string don't match up

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, hash, md5

I need to convert a password to an MD5 hash and compare it to the MD5 hash I get from the webservice.
If these two match, the user can login.

Let's say the user's password is '**cat**'. If I make a hash out of that I get `d077f244def8a70e5ea758bd8352fcd8`. This equals the hash I receive from the webservice. Now I know the code for creating the MD5 is correct.

However, when the password is '**çàt**', I get this hash: `727f8e931135b44b37eb147c8a7a56af`. The webservice gives me back this hash: `f571ca52b4e3c5a6f49675deaea89cac`.

So that's the problem. For some reason these 2 hashes of the same word are different, didn't know such a thing was even possible. 
It only happens when there's an accent or some other weird character in the password though, so I think it has something to do with encoding.

I tried using `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"çàt"];

char converted[([string length] + 1)];
[string getCString:converted maxLength:([string length] + 1) encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSString *converted_str = [NSString stringWithCString:converted encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Found here: [Convert UTF-8 encoding to ISO 8859-1 encoding with NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553388/how-to-convert-utf8-encoding-to-iso-8859-1-encoding)

But that doesn't give me the correct hash either.

I tried all the possible NSString encodings but none of em returned the right hash.

So what can I do about this. Is there something wrong with the code for converting the encoding? Or maybe it doesn't have anything to do with encoding (since trying other encodings isn't working)?

Comment: Lets type in `d077f244def8a70e5ea758bd8352fcd8` in Google, and you will see why a password should never be hashed with MD5, especially without a salt. There are key-derivation functions like BCrypt or PBKDF2 which are designed to hash passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the 727... you get is correct, it's what the md5 command line tool gives as well. So it's your server part that's broken - and as you already stated, it's probably just some wrong encoding - be careful when transmitting text to the server.

Answer (score 1):

It does have to do with text encoding. Remember that the MD5 hash works on bytes, not on characters. As such, the encoding of the text you feed into it matters!

Here are the byte sequences that hash to the results you're seeing:

```
d077f244def8a70e5ea758bd8352fcd8 = 63 61 74       ("cat", ASCII)

727f8e931135b44b37eb147c8a7a56af = c3 a7 c3 a0 74 ("çát", UTF-8 NFC)

f571ca52b4e3c5a6f49675deaea89cac = e7 e0 74       ("çát", ISO8859-1)
```

While working on this, please remember the following very important points:

- Not all characters can be represented in ISO8859-1. It's limited to characters found in Western European languages.
- There can be multiple representations of the same character, even in UTF-8. Most notably, accented characters such as "á" can be represented either as a single precomposed character (U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE), or as a combining sequence (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A + U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT). The results look the same (á vs. á), but will be treated as different strings by most comparison routines, as well as hashes, unless first normalized.

Answer (score 0):

With this method you return the md5 hashed string in Objective-c, before u have to import the common crypto library

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

-(NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input {
const char* str = [input UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
}
return ret;
```

}

then make sure that you are using the same encoding system in both parts, your app and your web service, i recommend to use "UTF-8" but if you are using "latin 1" then in your web service you should use "iso-850-1"